# Security around JNLP PersistenceService

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm working on a JavaFX application that runs embedded in a browser and I'd like to store application settings using the PersistenceService that's part of [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService).

I haven't used the PersistenceService before, and have a few questions about the PersistenceService:

(a) Does it encrypt or secure the data stored through it in any way?

(b) Is it a reasonable to store refresh tokens using the Persistence Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not encrypted automatically.  If you are going to store confidential data there you should encrypt it yourself (with a key that is stored only on the server side, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks very much -- that's what I was afraid of.

What doesn't make sense to me is that if someone decompiles the JavaFX app, and gets past the obfuscation, they would be able to call the same server-side resource as the application.  So even though they won't have the encryption key, they'll have access to the decrypted value of the confidential data.  I could prompt the user for a password (to use for the encryption), but that will make the application so much more painful to use. Shoot -- I don't see a very good option for storing confidential data, that isn't a pain for the end-user.

Comment: Technically it's implementation dependent.